# How do you calculate the P/E ratio by industry?

Tags: stocks, calculation, stock-valuation, stock-markets, price-earnings-ratio

I would like to know how to calculate the P/E ratio by industry. On [this website](http://in.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=DTV.O&exchange=XXCX), it displays the P/E ratio for the current stock, the industry and the sector:

```
FINANCIALS
             DTV.O  Industry    Sector
P/E (TTM):   12.84   38.88   15.37
EPS (TTM):   4.81    --  --
ROI:         19.26   22.72   15.30
ROE:         --      23.20   18.69
```

Does anyone know the formula ? My problem is that I have historical data about P/E by stock, and I need to calculate the P/E radio by industry.

Comment: If you click on the word "Broadcasting" on that page you can find the sector `Cyclical Consumer Goods & Services` and Industry `Broadcasting`. P/E is probably weighted by market-cap of all the companies within the group.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you're right. In this page,  http://in.reuters.com/sectors/industries/rankings?industryCode=18&view=value&page=-1&sortby=peexclxor&sortdir=DESC the p/e by industry is the average of the P/E of all stock within this industry

Comment: the idea of P/E by industry comes from this guy, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEypGm5ahCI his strategy is basically to pick stock which P/E is below the P/E of the industry. And because I don't know if he's right or not, I was planning to check that on my historical datas.

Comment: @user814064 - I'd not make such a blanket statement regarding P/E. It's one tool of many. And the Stock P/E compared to industry may also just be a data point, but not the only one. Low P/E may mean an underlying issue, and the earnings will drop to get that P/E back in line, not a price rise.

Comment: Here's a real simple article about how financial metrics like P/E can be modified without affecting a company's real value. http://www.investopedia.com/articles/02/041702.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sum the P/E ratio of all the companies in the industry and divide it by the number of companies to find the average P/E ratio of the industry.

> Average P/E ratio of industry  = Sum of P/E ratio of all companies in
>   Industry / Number of companies in industry

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I thought of sharing my two cents in case anybody came across it.

I would propose using the **median** instead of the mean. This would be a robust way against outliers. If some outlier companies are way more or way less than the rest, they would affect the mean, leading to wrong interpretations of your results.

Simply order the P/Es in ascending/descending order then take the **middle** value in the list.

Comment: While I like the idea of using a median, I don't think that a bog-standard median is correct.  Since the companies in an index are all of different sizes, you need to calculate the **weighted** median.